# How do i remove dll(s) from Nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Im using Visual Studio 2022 and created a Nuget Package using this article

https://arsenshnurkov.github.io/gentoo-mono-handbook/building-nupkg.htm

I run `nuget pack` and i see the nupg file and upload it to our Azure Artifacts. Below is the spec file

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>myProject.csproj</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>user</authors>
    <owners>user</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Test package 1</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2023</copyright>
    <tags>Tag test</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I noticed when i install this pack into a test application it includes some dlls that are not required for the end project to run.

After some research there are suggestions to change the .csproj to exclude it from Nuget when packing following this article https://www.jocheojeda.com/2019/07/22/how-to-exclude-package-dependencies-in-a-nuget-package/

but he writes the exact question i have in mind but no example of how to do this. In the article he quotes

*the answer depend on how now you create your NuGet package, in this case, I’m going to focus my answer on excluding the dependency in a package created by the info in the csproj file (**there is a different approach if you use the nuspec file**).*

I **dont** want to amend the `csproj` file but just the nuspec file. How could i leave out files that i dont want to have bundled with my package by amending the nuspec file?

Comment: Do you actually need a nuspec file at all? If your csproj file is an "SDK-style" one, I'd expect you to be able to package it without a nuspec file.

Comment: Im pretty new with packaging files using Nuget so im not so sure and just following the articles. The project being packed is a class library targeting .Net 4.7. I dont want to touch the .csproj file but more curious how to do this in the nuspec file but now confused as youre suggesting it could be done without it?

Comment: Yes, if you use an SDK-style csproj file (which is perfectly capable of targeting .NET 4.7) then you probably don't need a separate nuspec file. I find that's significantly easier to manage - and SDK-style project files are also generally much easier to work with (as they don't list every individual source file etc)

Comment: I would say im not using an SDK style csproj (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format) its just .Net Framework. If you are suggesting to change/convert it (i would need to research if this is possible) i just need to ensure it doesnt break existing functionality if i was to install this package and overwrite existing files on current applications if i convert to an SDK style?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "install this package" but you should be able to convert the project to an SDK-style project without breaking it, yes. I suspect there are various documents around for how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to include/exclude files from nuget packaging, you can add the  section to nuspec config file as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files).

Following your example, the files would exclude log files from your package. Using wildcards, you can exclude any other file/dll:

```
<package>
    <metadata>
    <id>myProject.csproj</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>user</authors>
    <owners>user</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Test package 1</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2023</copyright>
    <tags>Tag test</tags>
    </metadata>
    <files>     
        <file src="*.*" exclude="*.log" />
    </files>
</package>
```